# Python multiprocessing for loops/other iterables

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to figure out a way to use the multiprocessing package to reduce the amount of time it takes to process some code I have.

Essentially, I have a matching calculation done with multiple nested for loops that I would like to fully utilize the 12 core processor I have available. I've found some documentation and answers on for loops and multiprocessing, but it just doesn't seem to click in my head for some reason. Anyway...

I have two large dataframes, that I've converted into lists of lists to be able to iterate over them easier.

They both follow the same format, but have different values - so as an example the DFs/lists would look like this

#### TT and CT:

```
|user_id| hour1_avg | hour2_avg |....| hour24_avg| hour1_stdev | ... | hour24_stdev | 
|-------|-----------|-----------|----|-----------|-------------|-----|--------------|
| 12345 |   1.34    |   2.14    |----|   3.24    |    .942     |-----|      .834    | 
| 54321 |   2.14    |   3.10    |----|   6.26    |    .826     |-----|      .018    |
```

Which is then converted to a list of lists using `.values.to_list()`.

#### TTL and CTL:

```
[[12345, 1.34, 2.14,...3.24,.942,....834],[54321, 2.14, 3.10,...6.26, .826,....018], [etc]]
```

The code I have iterates through the two list of lists, computes a calculation for each hourly value, and then spits the paired result into a `pairs` list if all 24 hours meet the criteria in the `if` statement. Those that don't meet the criteria can be kicked out.

```py
pairs = [] #output for for loops

start_time = time.time()
for idx, a in enumerate(ttl): # iterate through primary list of list
    if idx % 12 != 0: #used to separate for 12 processors (0-11 to split processes manually)
        continue
    for b in ctl: # iterate through second list of list 
        i = 0
        tval_avg = [] # used to calculate average between computed variables in the loop
        for c in range(1,31): # iterate through hour avg and stdev 
            i += 1
            tval = np.absolute((a[c] - b[c])/np.sqrt((a[c+24]**2/31)+(b[c+24]**2/31))) 
            if math.isnan(tval) or tval > 2.04:
                break
            else:
                tval_avg.append(tval)
                if i == 24:  # checks to make sure each hour matches criteria to before being returned
                    pairs.append([a[0], b[0], a[2], a[3], np.mean(tval_avg)])
    if idx % 10 == 0 :
        print(idx) # check progress of loop
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time)) # show total time at the end
```

This works if I manually open 12 kernals in spyder and assign 0-11 to the `if idx %` statement and run them (allowing me to use more processors). My goal is to run everything in one kernal, using multiprocessing to assign 12 (or whatever is efficient) different "jobs" - one for each processor, and spit the result into a single dataframe. Is this possible with this type of code? If so, what types of changes would I need to make?

Sorry if this is complicated. I'd be happy to explain further if needed.

I've searched around SO for something similar to my specific issue, but haven't been able to find anything. I'm also having trouble understanding multiprocessing, and how it would be applied to this specific scenario, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How large are your dataframes? And how long does your computation take? And why don't you use `for i in range(1, 25)` instead of `for c in range(1, 31)`? You can probably save quite some time already by vectorizing your calculations.

Comment: Oh good catch. My actual dataframes have some additional columns up front for my own reference, that weren't critical for the example so I removed them. I'll update the code to reflect the sample DF. Also, the ```TT`` dataframe is (3000, 55) while the ```CT``` dataframe is (112000, 55). We tried vectorizing them, but the amount of data is too large and required an iterative process to kick out the non matching variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs in under 1.5 mins on my notebook with the large DFs. The non-multiprocessing variant isn't much slower, though.
***Edit***: That's actually only true when the threshold is so high that no (or very few) pairs are found. In case you get many pairs, the ipc overhead is so big that the non-multiprocessing variant is a lot faster. For me at least.

I've validated the result by changing the filter from `>2.04` to `>20` which is more appropriate for the uniform samples I've created.
Both our algorithms seem to produce the same list of pairs (once I've fixed the range and removed the `idx % 12` part).

Btw I used [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) to visualize the progress, that's a very handy library for that.

```
import math

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tqdm
import multiprocessing

avg_cols = [f"hour{i}_avg" for i in range(1, 25)]
stdev_cols = [f"hour{i}_stdev" for i in range(1, 25)]
columns = ["userid"] + avg_cols + stdev_cols
np.random.seed(23)
# threshod = 2.04
# rands_tt = np.random.rand(3000, 49)
# rands_ct = np.random.rand(112000, 49)
threshold = 20
rands_tt = np.random.rand(2, 49)
rands_ct = np.random.rand(10, 49)

multipliers = np.repeat([1000000, 5, 2], [1, 24, 24])[None, :]

TT = pd.DataFrame(data=rands_tt * multipliers, columns=columns)
CT = pd.DataFrame(data=rands_ct * multipliers, columns=columns)

pairs = []

tt_complete = TT.loc[:, columns].to_numpy()
ct_complete = CT.loc[:, columns].to_numpy()

avg = slice(1, 25)
stdev = slice(25, 49)
# do the **2/31 calculations only once
tt_complete[:, stdev] **= 2
tt_complete[:, stdev] /= 31

ct_complete[:, stdev] **= 2
ct_complete[:, stdev] /= 31


def find_pairs(tt_row):
    tvals = np.absolute(
        (tt_row[None, avg] - ct_complete[:, avg]) / np.sqrt(tt_row[None, stdev] + ct_complete[:, stdev])
    )

    # nan will propagate itself as max and when compared to 2.04 will return False
    valid_tval_idxs = np.where(tvals.max(axis=1) <= threshold)[0]
    mean_tvals = tvals.mean(axis=1)

    return [[tt_row[0], ct_complete[i, 0], tt_row[2], tt_row[3], mean_tvals[i]] for i in valid_tval_idxs]


# for tt_row in tqdm.tqdm(tt_complete):
#     pairs.extend(find_pairs(tt_row))


with multiprocessing.Pool(6) as pool:
    pairlist_iterable = pool.imap_unordered(find_pairs, tt_complete, chunksize=200)
    for pairlist in tqdm.tqdm(pairlist_iterable, total=len(tt_complete)):
        pairs.extend(pairlist)


ttl = TT.to_numpy().tolist()
ctl = CT.to_numpy().tolist()

pairs2 = []  # output for for loops

for idx, a in enumerate(ttl):  # iterate through primary list of list

    for b in ctl:  # iterate through second list of list
        i = 0
        tval_avg = []  # used to calculate average between computed variables in the loop
        for c in range(1, 25):  # iterate through hour avg and stdev
            i += 1
            tval = np.absolute((a[c] - b[c]) / np.sqrt((a[c + 24] ** 2 / 31) + (b[c + 24] ** 2 / 31)))
            if math.isnan(tval) or tval > threshold:
                break
            else:
                tval_avg.append(tval)
                if i == 24:  # checks to make sure each hour matches criteria to before being returned
                    pairs2.append([a[0], b[0], a[2], a[3], np.mean(tval_avg)])

print(pairs)   
print(pairs2)
print(pairs == pairs2)
```

The output is

```
100%|██████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 2150.93it/s]
[[517297.88384658925, 878265.8552092713, 3.8272987969845347, 1.4119792198355636, 6.95265573421445]]
[[517297.88384658925, 878265.8552092713, 3.8272987969845347, 1.4119792198355636, 6.95265573421445]]
True
```

Comment: This also makes sense. I'm trying to run your code as is, but when I get to the ```with multiprocessing.Pool(6) as pool:``` portion, nothing happens. It stays at 0 for almost 10 minutes, and I see no change in my CPU's utilization. I think I might be doing something incorrectly. I run that portion on its own after I've run everything above it to create the datasets, correct?

Comment: Nevermind, you're right - just the vectorization works well enough on its own without the multi-processing. After tinkering with it for a few hours I got it work on my original dataset, and it runs much faster than anything I had before. Thank you so much!

Comment: So, follow up question - how would I add the ability to count the number of matches per loop? In this instance, I want to filter out all users that dont match on all 24 hours. As it appears now, it seems to include all the users that matched at some point, breaking off after they dont match. So the first few hours of matches are extremely saturated with data I dont need. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think `all(tvals.nanmin(axis=0) < threshold)` will be true if there is at least one tval below threshold for every hour. If I understand you correctly, that is what you need.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. My goal basically is to kick out any pairs that have atleast one tval above threshold. Not removing the tval itself, but drop the entire match. So if one control user matches the first 10 tvals, but does not match on 11, their entire match would be removed and all values would be dropped. That way it's only those who match 100% below the threshold on all hours. But I'll give an update as soon as I can get this attempted. Thanks for the continued help!

Comment: So,  I tried this - but I dont think I did it right. I replaced the ```valid_tval_idxs``` var with a bit of this, so I have ```valid_tval_idxs = np.where(np.nanmin(tvals.all()) <= threshold)[0]```. Is this correct? I was getting errors elsewise, so I made a few changes for it to work. Not sure if I'm doing this right.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you via the comment section. Solving this requires a lot more information. I can just advise you to use Jupyter Notebook so you can develop faster and to break your problem down into a smaller piece so it's easier to work with. Once you get it running on the small sample, apply it to your larger dataset.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop is over `ttl`.
Move the code in the body of that loop into a helper function
that accepts `a` as input and
returns `(tval_avg, pairs)`.

Then use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) to repeatedly call that helper.

The return tuple will be serialized and sent back to the parent process.
You will need to combine results from individual worker bees
to obtain the same result your original code calculates.

Alternatively, you might prefer to serialize results from the helper
into uniquely named files.

Comment: This makes sense. How would this look in practice? I'm relatively new to Python and don't really know how I'd put that into actual usable code.